# Winter 14 causing errors?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, error, winter14

I have a very simple VF Page, that just has an action method that copies the address of the head of household to all the rest of the contacts to the household.  This has worked fine, but on Saturday when the Winter '14 preview release came out, it stopped working, and I get a ver odd jQuery error.  I have not used and jQuery on this page so it must be the SF code itself that is hitting the error.

Although I know this isn't an issue with the page or controller, I have added them just for reference.  Has anyone else run into this issue with the Winter 14 preview release???

**Here is my VF page**

```
<apex:page StandardController="Household__c" extensions="CopyHohAddressController" action="{!copyAddress}"> 

</apex:page>
```

**and here is the controller**

```
public class CopyHohAddressController {

    public Contact con                                  {get;set;}
    public Contact hoh                                  {get;set;}
    public Household_Affiliation__c houseAff            {get;set;}
    public Household__c house                           {get;set;}
    public list<Contact> consToUpdate                   {get;set;}{consToUpdate = new list<Contact>();}

    public CopyHohAddressController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        house = (Household__c)controller.getRecord();
        house = [Select Id, Name, Head_Of_Household__c From Household__c Where Id =: house.Id];
        hoh = [Select Id, Name, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode From Contact Where Id =: house.Head_Of_Household__c ];
    }

    public PageReference copyAddress(){
        set<Id> conIDs = new set<Id>();
        for(Household_Affiliation__c aff : [Select Id, Contact__c From Household_Affiliation__c Where Household__c =: house.Id And Status__c = 'Current']){
            if(aff.Contact__c != hoh.Id){
                conIDs.add(aff.Contact__c);
            }
        }
        consToUpdate = [Select Id, Name, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode, Anchor__c, Related_Member__c
                             From Contact Where Id in: conIDs];

        for(Contact c: consToUpdate){
            c.MailingStreet = hoh.MailingStreet;
            c.MailingCity = hoh.MailingCity;
            c.MailingState = hoh.MailingState;
            c.MailingPostalCode = hoh.MailingPostalCode;
        }

        if(!consToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            try{
                update consToUpdate;
            }
            catch(DmlException ex){
                ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
                return null;
            }   

        }

        string url;
        url = '/' + house.id;   

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(url);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }

}
```

**Here is the error I am getting in the console**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this in different browsers?

Comment: I have.  I just posted a separate and different rendering issue in another question that is happening since the Winter 14 release.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16376/another-winter-14-issue

Comment: This seems to be a winter '14 bug, It is unable to calculate right width for page.

Comment: Can you defined 'stopped working'.  The errors you list are javascript issues but the problem you state indicates its with the server side logic?

Comment: the page just goes blank and does nothing.  Prior to the Winter 14 release it worked as expected

Comment: Do you by any chance use jquery in a sidebar component? It shouldn't cause your vf page to stop working though.