# Another Winter 14 issue?

Tags: visualforce, winter14

So I have another issue VF issue that seems to be new since the Winter 14 release.  I have very simple quick add VF pages that can be accessed from a home page link component.  These have always worked and since the Winter 14 preview release I get the following odd behavior.

The page is wider than the specified pixel width I set in the window open properties of the VF page link.  Before the release, the page would adjust to the set width and properly display both columns of input fields.  This is the behavior I am getting now

**When I first open the page**

[image]

**And now if I try to scroll over to see the rest of the page**

[image]

I have tried in Chrome, Firefox and Safari so I dont think its a browser issue.  I am getting no errors in the browser console either.  Has anyone seen this yet and how do I fix???

Comment: Can you switch of the development mode ?Also whats the visualforce version of your page ?

Comment: Its version 27.  I reverted back to 27 because of the managed package error.  I took it off development mode and it made no difference

Comment: I have the same issue.
In winter 14, pageBlockSection is rendered in html to give following table structure
&lt;table&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;th&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;th&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;th&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;th&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
While in earlier versions it was rendered in html like this-
&lt;table&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
Now because of this &lt;th&gt; instead of &lt;td&gt;, this issue is arising. No css is working. We can't control the

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a CSS issue with it setting itself to the width of the window not the width of the content.

You could probably fix it with some CSS overrides, but I'd raise a case with Salesforce for them to fix it and see if it gets cleaned up in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override this:

```
.apexp .bPageBlock .detailList {
    width: 100%;
}
```

With either an exact width, or you'll need to capture the relative width of the window and feed that to a class.